# POST from nodemcu to orion, 411 error but Content-Length exists in headers

Tags: json, post, fiware-orion, nodemcu

I send a POST this 2 values (temp & humi) in a json object to my orion server but it fails with an orion error message:

```
<orionError>
  <code>411</code>
  <reasonPhrase>Length Required</reasonPhrase>
  <details>Zero/No Content-Length in PUT/POST/PATCH request</details>
</orionError>
```

Although a "Content-Length: " header is included (see below in code).
I´m lost now...

My code (executed in ESPlorer v0.2.0rc2) is:

```
humi=10
temp=20

function postValores(level)
    connout = nil
    connout = net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)

    connout:on("receive", function(connout, payloadout)
        print (payloadout);
        if (string.find(payloadout, "400 Bad Request") ~= nil) then
            print("BAD POST");
        end
        if (string.find(payloadout, "411 Bad Request") ~= nil) then
            print("BAD POST");
        end   
        if (string.find(payloadout, "200 OK") ~= nil) then
            print("GOOD POST");
        end
    end)

    connout:on("connection", function(connout, payloadout)

        print ("Posting...")

        local var = '{"id": "Sala1", "type": "Sala", "attributes": [{"name": "temperature", "type": "float","value": "'..temp..'" },{"name": "humidity", "type": "float", "value": "'..humi..'"}]}'
        local num = string.len(var)   
        local postval = "POST /v1/contextEntities/ HTTP/1.1\r\n"     
          .." Host: 130.206.124.50\r\n" 
          .." Content-Length: "
          ..num.."\r\n"
          .." Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
          .." Accept: application/json\r\n"
          .."\r\n"
          ..var.."\r\n"   
        print (postval)
        connout:send(postval)
    end)

    connout:on("disconnection", function(connout, payloadout)
        connout:close()
        collectgarbage()
    end)
    connout:connect(1026,'130.206.124.50')
end
tmr.alarm(2, 16000, 1, function() postValores(0) end)
```

---

I send:

```
Posting...
POST /v1/contextEntities/ HTTP/1.1
 Host: 130.206.124.50
 Content-Length: 157
 Content-Type: application/json
 Accept: application/json

{"id": "Sala1", "type": "Sala", "attributes": [{"name": "temperature", "type": "float","value": "20" },{"name": "humidity", "type": "float", "value": "10"}]}
```

And the response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required
Content-Length: 163
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Tue, 16 Feb 2016 13:43:12 GMT

<orionError>
  <code>411</code>
  <reasonPhrase>Length Required</reasonPhrase>
  <details>Zero/No Content-Length in PUT/POST/PATCH request</details>
</orionError>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorted!.

I was adding a blank before every header. 
This is the right code for the payload:

```
local postval = "POST /v1/contextEntities HTTP/1.1\r\n"     
          .."Host: 130.206.124.50\r\n" 
          .."Accept: application/json\r\n"
          .."Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
          .."Content-Length: "
          ..num.."\r\n"
          .."\r\n"
          ..var.."\r\n"
```

Comment: You wouldn't have to deal with that sort of bugs if you used the [NodeMCU HTTP module](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/http/) (currently only in `dev` branch, use http://nodemcu-build.com/).